# Rotate non-Bit Arrays in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

Using `rol(a,1)` on `a=BitArray([true,true,false])` yields the following result:

```
julia> rol(a,1)
3-element BitArray{1}:
true
false
true
```

How can I rotate non-Bit Arrays? For example I have `b=[1,2,3,4]` and would like to get the following output: `[2,3,4,1]`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you're looking for [`circshift`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/arrays.html#Base.circshift):

```
julia> circshift([1,2,3,4], -1)
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 3
 4
 1
```

Comment: This is probably a good candidate for API consolidation since these functions are so similar.

Answer (score 3):

`circshift` does what you want, as per the accepted answer. However, just to add to this, you can also manipulate the indices manually:

```
julia> a = [1,2,3,4];
julia> a[[2:end; 1]] |> show
  [2,3,4,1]
julia> a[[3:end; 1:2]] |> show
  [3,4,1,2]
```

In fact, what you're doing here is <s>'linear'</s> 'integer array' indexing, so the number of elements can be more than 4 (i.e. the same positions can be accessed multiple times or not at all):

```
julia> a[[3:end; 1:2; 1; 2; 2; 1]] |> show
  [3,4,1,2,1,2,2,1]

julia> a[[1:end; end-1:-1:1]] |> show
  [1,2,3,4,3,2,1]
```

The same applies to higher dimensional arrays:

```
julia> b = [1 2 3 4; 2 3 4 5; 3 4 5 6; 4 5 6 7];
julia> b[[2:end; 1], [1:3; 2:end; 1]]
  4×7 Array{Int64,2}:
     2  3  4  3  4  5  2
     3  4  5  4  5  6  3
     4  5  6  5  6  7  4
     1  2  3  2  3  4  1
```

Comment: This isn't what is commonly referred to as linear indexing — that's when you use one index to span multiple dimensions.

Comment: Thanks @MattB. what is the preferred terminology for this in Julia then? I borrowed the term from matlab where this is what they call it (in matlab this is a reference to matlab being column-major-order, but I suppose Julia being column-major-order too doesn't imply it should use the same term). I know python calls this "integer indexing" instead.

Comment: @MattB. hm, the julia docs seem to call it linear indexing too http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/devdocs/subarrays/ . Are you referring to something different?

Comment: I typically just call it non-scalar indexing, but your edit is good, too. Linear indexing can be non-scalar, but the two are orthogonal concepts. Linear indexing is when you use `A[5]` to refer to `A[1,2]` in a 4x2 array. This is how MATLAB uses the term, too.

Comment: Ah, ok, I see what you mean. To be fair, I think it's still linear indexing, it's just that it can be applied separately to dimensions. This is why a[:,:] will work on a 3D array, for instance (the second ':' is a linear index applied to the remaining dimensions). Anyway, thanks for clarifying; I agree 'integer array indexing' probably sounds clearer anyway.